# Using compiler explorer in IDE mode with msvc

Tags: c++, cmake, cl, godbolt

When using compiler explorer in IDE mode with CMake, I can easily switch between gcc or clang versions but msvc gives me: `<Compilation failed: Request failed: HTTP error code 400>`.
[A basic example](https://godbolt.org/z/n5dj76K9E).

Is it possible to make it works with msvc, and how ?

Comment: The only reason I can think of for getting an HTTP download error code when running a C++ compiler is a virus infestation, a rather dumb virus, that is unable to download more payload. I wonder if anyone else can come up with a better explanation.

Comment: MSVC support is pretty limited these days in godbolt. @SamVarshavchik a virus doesn't seem a likely explanation, more likely just a bad error message translation, the full message is `spawn cmake ENOENT`. My guess would be that cmake simply isn't installed in the MSVC environment

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thx for the feedback. Where do you get this error message?

Comment: Its the text of the HTTP 400 response, you can see it in your browser's developer tools

Comment: @AlanBirtles. OK, I'm not used to that but using it I've got ["Method Not Allowed"](https://godbolt.org/api/compiler/vcpp_v19_latest_x64/cmake)

Comment: You can't simply open the failing request in a new tab as it'll change it to a GET request (which isn't correct, hence your error message), you need to inspect the response within the original page, e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NneRr.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Godbolt doesn't support cmake with MSVC https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/3216